# Rails 3.2, how to change :from value in a mailer instead default (GMail)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmail, contact-form

I have built a contact us form and I nicely get the emails in my gApps inbox. However, the received emails show the default :from value of the site. I would like them to appear sent from the email users type in the email field of them form. So, when I hit 'reply' it takes the user address as the address the email has to be sent.

I have tried this, but it does not work. Any idea why?

notifications_mailer.rb

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: "info@hikultura.com"

  def new_contact(message)
      @message = message
      mail(:subject => "[hiKultura.com] #{message.subject}",
        :from => message.email)
  end
end
```

ContactController

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @message = Contactmessage.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Contactmessage.new(params[:contactmessage])

    if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_contact(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

UPDATE

I followed similar cases I found in SO regarding :reply_to and GMail. But, still shows the :to email address when I hit reply. What am I missing???

notifications_mailer.rb

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

   default :from => 'no-reply@mydomain.com'

  def new_contact(message)
      @message = message
      mail(:reply_to => "mierda@hotmail.com",
      :subject => "[mydomain.com] #{message.subject}", 
      :to => "admin@mydomain.com"
      )
  end
end
```

Comment: What does message.email return?

Comment: How can I know that? I assumed it should work because 'message.subject' content gets added to the subject line.

Comment: Where are you calling it from? What are you passing in?

Comment: added the controller.. that might make things clearer

Comment: well.... reading on the net just discover that gmail does not let you override the :from value.... shite!

Answer (score 5):

Most SMTP providers (Gmail, etc.) won't let you send an email from an address other than the address associated with the account that you are logging in to the SMTP server with, which in your case is probably the default from address configured in your app.  If you think about it, that makes a lot of sense for security/SPAM protection.  Would you want anyone to be able to send an email that showed your email address as the from address?  I sure wouldn't.  An alternative is to use :reply_to.  When you hit reply in your email program it should use this if it's present.

```
  mail(:subject => "[hiKultura.com] #{message.subject}",
    :reply_to => message.email)
```

Comment: I do agree with the logic behind. However, I do not manage to get  :reply_to working. I updated that bit of code. Thanks

Comment: You can also just use the `from` parameter as described in the API documentation. But then you have to make sure that your SMTP server is configured correctly to allow relaying, probably using authenticated SMTP. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail

Comment: is that possible with gmail? As far as I understand GMail does not allow you to use :from